# How to create a lambda function in region wise

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have zip file

`lambda_function.py` have below contents

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Success')
    }
```

Convert above lambda_function.py to function.zip

WHile executing the below command

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name sample --zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler  lambda_function.lambda_handler  --runtime python3.8 --role arn:aws:iam::1111:role/lambda-role
```

I got below one

```
{
    "FunctionName": "sample",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:1111:function:sample",
    "Runtime": "python3.8",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::1111:role/lambda-role",
    "Handler": "index.handler",
    "CodeSize": 306,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "LastModified": "2021-04-28T06:47:29.174+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "LYco0RgztxYIuoMA=",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "bb285d6",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful"
}
```

My lambda function is in `eu-central-1`
I want my lambda function has to be in `us-east-1`. How is this possible

I have changed 'Default region' using `aws-configure` but

after `aws create...` i m getting below error

`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://lambda.eu-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions"`

Comment: You just need to set the correct region, as you did with `aws configure` or with environment variable or as parameter `--region us-east-1`. Give us more details about your error so we can help you more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I did it was I configured the region field of the credentials of the user

- Which if you are in a Linux machine could be in the file located in `~/.aws/credentials`
- Or could also be set via `export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1`

First run, using `ap-southeast-1`:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials  # Or could also be via environment variable -> export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-1
[myself]
aws_access_key_id = xxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxx
region = ap-southeast-1
$ aws lambda --profile=myself create-function --function-name my_first_deploy --zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler  lambda_function.lambda_handler  --runtime python3.8 --role arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxx
{
    "FunctionName": "my_first_deploy",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:xxxx:function:my_first_deploy",
    "Runtime": "python3.8",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxx",
    "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
    "CodeSize": 306,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "LastModified": "2021-04-28T07:23:34.828+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "xxxx",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "xxxx",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful",
    "PackageType": "Zip"
}
```

[image]

Second run, using `us-east-1`:

```
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials  # Or could also be via environment variable -> export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
[myself]
aws_access_key_id = xxxx
aws_secret_access_key = xxxx
region = us-east-1
$ aws lambda --profile=myself create-function --function-name my_second_deploy --zip-file fileb://function.zip --handler  lambda_function.lambda_handler  --runtime python3.8 --role arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxx
{
    "FunctionName": "my_second_deploy",
    "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:xxxx:function:my_second_deploy",
    "Runtime": "python3.8",
    "Role": "arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxxx",
    "Handler": "lambda_function.lambda_handler",
    "CodeSize": 306,
    "Description": "",
    "Timeout": 3,
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "LastModified": "2021-04-28T07:29:51.221+0000",
    "CodeSha256": "xxxx",
    "Version": "$LATEST",
    "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
    },
    "RevisionId": "xxxx",
    "State": "Active",
    "LastUpdateStatus": "Successful",
    "PackageType": "Zip"
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286332/accessdeniedexception-coming-while-cross-account-amazon-standard-sqs-queue